# How to disable CDC for a table manually?

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I dropped a table before disabling CDC for that. Now when I recreated the table and tried enabling CDC it says that capture instance already exists. I can use a different Capture Instance name but need to know if there is anyway to drop the associated capture instance manually.

When  I delete a table through SSMS GUI it drops CDC tables too. But this time I dropped the table using code and it didn't disable or remove CDC. Hence the trouble. Ms documentation talks about a hot fix if Change Table are removed by mistake. But I have removed the base table. Any clues on how to remove this capture instance for the dropped table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out a way. I removed all the records related to that table from all CDC system tables and tried recreating the capture instance with same name. It worked!

Comment: Have you got a code example, when you said all the system tables? What ones? Having the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while now.. dont remember. But it was not hard... Just spend some time on it and you will figure out...

Answer (score 10):

Here are the steps I took to remove an orphaned capture instance in CDC:

```
DROP FUNCTION [cdc].[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_(tablename)]
DROP FUNCTION [cdc].[fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_(tablename)]
```

Then run the following:

```
declare @objid int
set @objid = (select object_id from cdc.change_tables where capture_instance = 'your orphaned capture instance')

delete from cdc.index_columns where object_id = @objid
delete from cdc.captured_columns where object_id = @objid
delete from cdc.change_tables where object_id = @objid
```

At that point you should be able to re-create your capture instance via sp_cdc_enable_table as normal.

Answer (score 4):

I had to execute one more step in addition to the REPLY by pdanke:

```
DROP TABLE cdc.<capture_insance>_CT
```

My cdc orphan may have come about when I restored a database where change data capture had been enabled.  In my case,

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture
```

resulted in one entry where `source_schema` and `source_table` were both `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

It's Simple

Just use the following Script

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table 'schema_name','Source_Table_Name','CDC_Table_Name'